# ASP.NET MVC routing with multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a `ManageController` with several action methods (`Index` and `Details`) which have parameters "group" and "key" and I want to setup my link like this:

```
http://localhost:49900/Manage/1
http://localhost:49900/Manage/Details/1/sample
```

But instead the link goes like this

```
http://localhost:49900/Manage?group=1
http://localhost:49900/Manage/Details?group=1&key=sample
```

This here is my routing setup:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Manage",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{group}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "Index", group = "" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ManageDetails",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{group}/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "Details", group = "", key = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Controller action methods:

```
public ActionResult Index(string group)
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Details(string group, string key)
{
    return View();
}
```

Action Links:

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Manage", new { group = "1" })">Manage</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Manage", new { group = "1", key = "sample" })">Manage Details</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use the following routes:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ManageDefault",
            url: "{controller}/{group}", // <= the {action} is omitted
            defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "Index", group = "" }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ManageDetails",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{group}/{key}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Manage", action = "Details", group = "",
                            key = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Your problem in the `ManageDefault` route declaration: **it become universal when using format like `"{controller}/{action}/{group}"`**. Therefore, the second template will never take place.

The difference from your code is only removing the `{action}` section in the first `MapRoute()`. This should serve the `http://localhost:49900/Manage/1` URL format and in the same time the second route template will be used as the default.

---

In some cases using Attribute Routing may be easier to serve routes like in your case.

See the following post: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET MVC 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)